# Excel Formula: Sum Column of Minutes, into summary in format DD:HH:MM

Tags: excel, format, sum

I have the following column as an example:

```
Variance (Minutes)
-600
-600
-600
-600
-600
-600
-600
```

It adds up to `-4200`. This is

```
 -2.91 days or

 -2 Days and 22hours
```

I dont know how to add the values up, and then convert that to -2 days , 22 hours, 0 minutes.

This is the closest i got (without the summing portion) (I set the value in A1 as -2.91):

```
=INT(A1) & ":" & TEXT(A1-INT(A1), "h:mm")
```

but I need RoundDown, otherwise it converts it to `-3:2:09`
since it thinks that -2.91 is -3 (rounds up)

So I use RoundDown, which produces a slightly better result

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0) &":"  & TEXT(A1-INT(A1), "h:mm")
```

produces:

```
-2:2:09
```

but its still way off the correct -2 days , 22 hours, 0 minutes

Could someone please help me with a formula ( I cannot select it manually, it is used in a generated report)
to sum up a column of minutes, and show it in format `dd,hh,mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 1440 minutes in a day. And Excel when using the default (for Windows versions) 1900 date system cannot express negative date/time values.  Given those limitations, and also given the fact that you apparently do not need your results to be a real number, here are two possible formulas to use which will give the results you show above

```
=TEXT(SIGN(SUM(A1:A7)),";-;;") &TEXT(ABS(SUM(A1:A7))/1440,"d"" days, ""h"" hours, ""m"" minutes""")

=TRUNC(SUM(A1:A7)/1440) & " days, " & TEXT(ABS(SUM(A1:A7))/1440,"h"" hours, ""m"" minutes""")
```

Comment: That is the best, most compact solution I have yet seen. Brilliant. Thank you so much